# How to use database connection strings in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I've just started ASP.NET for real, and I was wondering if it is possible to use connection strings from Data Sources instead of hard-coding them. I've added my connection in Data Sources and it works, and I can also drag a table to a page in design mode, but I can't figure out how to access it in code. Here's what I get when I drag it in:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="xxx" HeaderText="xxx" 
            SortExpression="xxx" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="xxx" HeaderText="xxx" 
            SortExpression="xxx" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString1 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT xxx FROM xxx">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: isn't the string stored in the web.config?

Comment: @melaos: Yes: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="xxxConnectionString1" connectionString="xxx"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>` But how do I get to xxxConnectionString1?

Comment: what's your problem ? why you drag table on your page ? Does your gridview show record ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the connection string in code behind like this

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Why he need to get this in code behind, since he can directly get in the SQL datasource he is using.

Comment: @Muhammad I'm not sure but I think that's what the OP is asking for `but I can't figure out how to access it in code`.

Answer (score 6):

I think your question is.. how do you access the connection string property that you see as

`ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxConnectionString1 %>"` in your aspx page right?

As Bala R mentioned...

use

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxConnectionString1"].ToString();`

but in order to do this, you should add the reference to System.Configuration.

i.e.

`Imports System.Configuration`

Answer (score 1):

The above posts are accurate, you'll want to explore the system.configuration assembly / namespace.  text content can be stored in AppSettings or ConnectionStrings.  its worth understanding how they both work moving forward.